# Login dialog on software app

Tags: login

I´m building a dialogue for a software application.

The main purpose of the dialogue is to make it easier for new users to create a new account. They need this account to use the software. So, old users are going to see this too but they already have an account.

So focusing on the new users this is the process:

They want to login and a new window appears. Like this:

[image: mockup showing initial log in dialog with text entry field for email address, check box to remember user, check boxes to choose either 'current member' or 'new account', field for password and button to continue]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frV6yW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

They have to put their email first, then if they don´t have an account they select the "No, I´m new to Yalala, I need to create an account". When they select that choice, the other choice (YES! I ALREADY...) puts in grey (like disabled) and the button of "continue" change to "create account" like in this:

[image: mockup showing initial log in dialog with text entry field for email address, check box to remember user, check boxes to choose either 'current member' or 'new account' ('new account' checked, 'current member' disabled), field for password and button to create account]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9uo48.png)</sup>

Then we show a new dialogue saying that the account has been created and that we have sent them an email to active it.

Is the dialogue too complicated? Is it too unfamiliar?

Comment: Is this the sort of question you're after? http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/best-way-to-combine-sign-in-and-sign-up-in-the-same-form

Comment: This is exactly the pattern that Amazon uses.

Comment: Can you just post links to the images you want to show? If you don't have 10 rep yet, you can't embed images.

Comment: yes, i can´t post images :( i don´t know how to tell you better the idea. But it´s just like brendon says, similar to amazon but equal.

Comment: but what do you think about this dialogue having the knowledge that the main goal is to facilitate the process for new users? is this dialogue bad for the ux?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1:
Just wanted to confirm if you are showing one more dialogue to confirm about account creation. Because, if you are showing up one more dialogue on top when there is already one dialogue already opened, it might not look good UX practice.

Scenario 2:
When user click on 'Create Account', the dialogue box closes and new dialogue box opens.
In this case, also, it does not looks proper to me as user may not be able to understand what is happening on screen. He is shown up with second immediate dialogue after first dialogue.

In both cases, I would recommend that you should display the success message in that dialogue itself rather than leaving user roam around clicking on these 2 dialogues. I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Ok, I will take care about that. I was thinking on the 2 scenario. The user click on "create account" and the screen refresh with the dialogue "thank you your account was create successfully! etc...." and then he close the window. But only that, refresh that screen, not open an other dialogue.

Comment: thank you for your comments, it´s difficult to tell you how it looks like because i can´t put any image yet :(

Comment: That is fine. I can understand the scenario now more clearly. If that is the same thing you are implementing, then it is absolutely fine at UX level.

Answer (score 0):

From another answer on ux.stackexchange,

Something like this would be better.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gARts.jpg]

Credit - [Nikita Prokopov](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/3740/nikita-prokopov)

Also, Amazon does the same thing you suggested, but I'm not a fan of it.

[image]

Comment: yeah. the idea is similar to amazon. But what do you think about doing this? is it good for the user experience or not?

Comment: In my opinion, No. The 1st design makes more sense. If the user is already registered, he can simply click on the sign in tab. It's a neater solution. **Edit:** Another factor that makes me prefer it is that both the tabs look similar, thus, it is not a big experience shift for the user.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions, i will follow them :)